# How to accommodate 8 buttons in a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uialertview

[image]i ve issue in alertview.. Initially i had 6 buttons in my alertview.. Then i had to add two more buttons into my alertview.. when i added two more buttons, the frame size becomes an issue..

Kindly refer the screenshot..

```
-(IBAction)FilterButton:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:nil
                           message:@"\n\n\n\n\n"
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                           otherButtonTitles:@"Customer",@"Contact",@"Lead",@"Team Member",@"Ex-Team Member",@"Inactive Customer",@"All Contacts",nil];

    [alert1 show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {

        case 1:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where ContactType = 'CUS' and isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;            
        }
        case 2:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where ContactType = 'CT' and isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;            
        }
        case 3:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where ContactType = 'LD' and isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;            
        }       
        case 4:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where ContactType = 'TM' and isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where ContactType = 'ETM' and isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where ContactType = 'INACUS' and isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from pu_Contacts where isDeleted ='0';"];
            [self selected];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Manoj Why stop at 8?

Comment: It will be better that you have a more option in the alertview and accordingly use the actionsheet to display the rest of the options. As per the coding standards the UI will be quite messed up in this case.

Comment: @Fogmeister : I ve uploaded the screenshot..

Comment: Make use of UIActionSheet

Comment: UIActionSheet is best for this purpose.. or else create ur custom menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your create code adding button in Alertview but its hard to manage it so i suggest you to using UIActionsheet like bellow code:-

```
  UIActionSheet *MultipleAcions = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Customer",@"Contact",@"Lead",@"Team Member",@"Ex-Team Member",@"Inactive Customer",@"All Contacts",nil];
    MultipleAcions.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [MultipleAcions showInView:self.view];
```

it's look linke bellow screenshot:-

[image]

and you can get each button's index using bellow UIActionsheet's Delegate:-

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheets clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: This is better use of the iOS controls but still requires the user to choose from 8 options. It's too much to throw at the user in one go.

Answer (score 3):

First off, there is no screenshot. (OK, this is fixed now).

Second, it looks like you are using `UIAlertView` to ask the user what they would like to do.

This is not what a `UIAlertView` is for. A `UIAlertView` is to inform the user that something happened that they need to know about.

What you need to be using is a `UIActionSheet`. These are designed for asking the user to make a decision based on an action they have just taken. i.e. press the "camera" button, ask the user if they want to take a photo or select from the camera roll.

This is all in the Human Interface Guidelines.

Third, if you need to put 8 choices plus a cancel on the screen then you're doing it wrong. Find another way of making all those available to the user without using 8 buttons.

Other options to look at...

You're writing an iPap app.

You could put all the options into a `UITableView` inside a `UIPopOverController`. A UITableView is more suited to displaying a large number of choices.

Similar to above use a `UIPickerView` inside a pop over. Again, this is more suited to a large number of choices. It also makes it easier for the user to understand that they are selecting one of the choices.

There could be any number of ways of doing this.

Comment: I've seen the screenshot. Still everything in the answer (except the first part) is relevant.

Comment: I'd recommend too a UITableView (in a UIAlertView, like when iOS scans for WiFi), or a UIPicker which could be put in a UIActionSheet, with a preference for the UIPicker.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you create a view with all the buttons you need and show it?

UIAlertview is not for this purpose

> According to Docs
>
> Use the UIAlertView class to display an alert message to the user. An
>   alert view functions similar to but differs in appearance from an
>   action sheet